# In laravel 5.4. composer update FatalThrowableError Class 'Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\LaravelFilemanagerServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel

I was using laravel 5.4. When I tried to install a package I ran a command for composer update which leads to an error below (1/1)

> Fatal Throwable Error Class
>   'Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\LaravelFilemanagerServiceProvider' not
>   found

Comment: Which package (and version)? Do you have more Stacktrace / Error Output?

Comment: Did you add the provider to your app config before running the composer update?

Comment: Ya I have that provider before running the composer update.

Comment: did you already tried `composer dump-autoload` ?
If you still get the same error, please delete `vendor` directory and `composer.lock` file then do `composer install` again

Answer (score 0):

Check if it helps you because it had solved my issue.

Make sure you have the aliases and providers in config/app

and then make sure you update composer on the live server.

You also need the config file for file manager by running

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_config`

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_public`

The missing config file was my issue.

Or Try this, put this

```
Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\LaravelFilemanagerServiceProvider::class
```

above the

```
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class
```

in your providers

Comment: I have tried all the above it is showing the same issue.

Comment: have you properly added the classes above mentioned ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, edit your php.ini file and uncomment these two lines:

```
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
```

then delete composer.lock file and run below code in CMD:

```
Composer install
```

then run

```
Composer dump auto-load
```

hope its could help :)